# Why didn't Obi-Wan take another apprentice during the Clone Wars? (after Anakin became a Knight)

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, jedi-training

During the Clone Wars, Anakin is a Jedi Knight and has his own Padawan (Ahsoka).

Why didn't Obi-Wan take another Padawan apprentice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obi-Wan is on the Jedi Council, and thus no longer has an apprentice. We don't see any other member of the Council (Yoda, Windu, Ki-Adi-Mundi, etc.) with Padawans. They may teach Younglings in a class (as we see Yoda doing), but are no longer focused on ONE trainee. They are concerned with all Jedi, and the Republic as a whole, at that point.

[Depa Billaba](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Depa_Billaba) training [Kanan Jarrus](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kanan_Jarrus) is a notable exception, but we only find that out after Star Wars Rebels was released. Since she didn't get much screen time in the movies, we can assume the restriction only applied to senior members of the Jedi Council.

Comment: Ahem - http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kanan_Jarrus / http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Depa_Billaba

Comment: Um, let me think of a reason... 1. Star Wars Rebels isn't canon. 2. She's a girl, she didn't have to follow the rules. 3. She's the exception that proves the rule. 4. It's a retcon, Kanan/Caleb doesn't appear in the Clone Wars or the movies. 5. *points behind you* What's that? *runs away*

Comment: I think Rebels is supposed to be canon now.

Comment: @MarkRogers SW: Rebels is indeed part of the ***full*** Disney canon, along with the seven films.

Comment: The comment software stripped out my sarcasm tags. I would think item 5 would have given you a hint it wasn't a serious response.

Comment: @CigarDoug - Ha, sorry my broken attention span has a tendency to stop at a sentence and half... You may want to edit your answer, though to reflect the one exception and why you think that is.

Comment: But I don't have a good explanation, that's why I only made a comment.

Comment: @CigarDoug - Fair enough, its just a suggestion.  Its possible a few people might be like me, they'll just read the first comment and assume you missed a point and downvote or something.  The comments are considered by some to be for improving the text of an answer or question.

Answer (score 8):

The very short answer is that it was because it **wasn't the will of the Jedi Council.** At the start of the Clone Wars film, we learn that Kenobi did indeed discuss (with Yoda) the possibility of getting a new Padawan learner. Ahsoka Tano was sent, but in a surprise move Yoda assigned her to Anakin Skywalker rather than Kenobi.

The clear implication seems to be that Obi-Wan wasn't assigned a new Padawan because he was expected *to keep an eye on the both of them*.

> *"It'll be here," Kenobi said, exuding energy. As always, he seemed
>   felt invigorated by a fight. Anakin wondered if he had those
>   frenzied killing moments too. Kenobi hooked his lightsaber to his belt
>   and jogged toward the plaza, where they'd set up a landing area. "Time
>   for reinforcements, supplies, and perhaps my new Padawan."*
>
> *Anakin's stomach sank a little. Dead weight. It distracted him from
>   his brush with darkness not darkness, no and he seized it. A change of
>   problem really was as good as a rest. "This isn't the time or the
>   place to train a Padawan, Master. They're a liability."* - <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Clone Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(novel))</sup></sub>

On at least one occasion, Yoda threatened to transfer her guardianship to Obi-wan, something that wouldn't be a possibility if he was encumbered with his own learner

> *"Master Obi-Wan," he said, bowing. "Master Yoda." Yoda fixed him with
>   a critical stare. "Trouble you have with your new Padawan, I hear." "I
>   was explaining the situation to Master Yoda," Kenobi said. "If not
>   ready for the responsibility of a Padawan you are, then perhaps to
>   Obi-Wan she should go..."* -  <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Clone Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: I had this very thought when I was adding the exception you brought up about Depa Billaba. It's not that she was out in the field, Obi-Wan was out in the field as well... with both Ani and Ahsoka. You beat me to the punch.

Comment: I think it's a signal as to how immature/dangerous the Council think Anakin is, that they've assigned him a Padawan to try to **calm him the hell down** along with leaving him with his original mentor.

Comment: And yet they had regular interactions with Darth Sidious and none of them got a Spider-Sense (TM) vibe about Evil Incarnate. I think it's plot neutrinos, not midichlorians, that makes up the Force.

Comment: @CigarDoug - Hard to see, the dark side is